# Compatibility problems in deploying c# win form application

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I am facing a lot of trouble while deploying a windows form application on a CD. I have made the application in .NET framework 2.0 and I want to include the setup for the framwork with the installation disk. The application is to run on WindowsXP(damn, user requirement). I tried deploying it with 1 click deployment in VS2010 but the setup does not run on winXP.(Error-.NET framework 4.0 required to run the application). Is there any way of deploying the app which can run on winXP(.NET 2.0), win7(.NET 4.0)-32 bit as well as 64 bit environment.

Comment: You develop 2.0v or 4.0v .NET application?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/d3e9c99d-a108-4b42-8c6b-dbd5c2850e61/

Comment: Look at Wix (Windows Installer XML) for building your MSI, much more flexible. You may have to build a bootstrapper (setup.exe) that determins what is already on the target system and then runs the correct MSIs for that platform.

Comment: .NET is forward compatible, you do not need 4.0 in order to run on Windows 7 etc.

Comment: Just target it against the .NET Framework 2.0. You cannot support both..  Of course much easier just to require .NET 4.0 since it supports XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32 bit app will run on 32 or 64 bit operating systems.

A .NET 2.0 application will run on .NET 2.0 or .NET 4.0.

Sounds like your installer is the only dependency on .NET 4.  Check the publishing prerequisites you have set on your project.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't provide a .Net 2.0 pre-requisite for deployment projects. A MSDN support rep explained (?) this in [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/d3eb2b4c-2af2-4ca6-a525-756d4d453298):

> In VS 2010, it doesn’t support you to set .NET Framework 2.0 as
>   prerequisite. You can set .NET 3.5 SP1 client profile instead.
>   Although your application is still build target to .NET 2.0, .NET 3.5
>   client profile is a light weight .NET framework run time which
>   supports to run .NET 2.0 based application. So Microsoft removes .NET
>   2.0 from the prerequisite list.

There's a solution though in that thread:

> If you take the .NET 2.0 package from the VS2008 bootstrapper packages
>   folder and copy it to the corresponding location for VS2010, it works
>   fine. I tested it in a virtual machine running Windows XP and no .NET.
>
> On Vista or Windows 7, the VS2008 packages are here:
>
> c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX (this is .NET 2.0)
>
> On Vista or Windows 7, the VS2010 packages are here:
>
> c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\BootStrapper\Packages

See the other posts in the thread for more detail.